# Arch linux: restore session with running programs after running out of battery

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, session, restore, battery

I have Lenovo notebook with Arch linux. When I run out of battery and my notebook dies, after starting it. It freshly boots new session. Is there a way to restore previous session and continue in it ?

PS: I use systemd, xserver and i3wm

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have your laptop set up to hibernate when it is almost out of battery?

Comment: If you make answer with some elegant way to achieve it, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First setup hibernation on arch,
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation

Then create a udev rule to hibernate on low battery percentage,
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/laptop#Hibernate_on_low_battery_level

Haven't tested the udev rule myself but should work.

Comment: The real answer. That, or doing everything in a Virtual Machine and save the execution state. Since one can hibernate with a swap file, a swap partition is not needed.